# FORMAT para Fecha dentro de un CASE - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy realizando un filtro de fecha en un case, pero quiero que esa fecha tenga 20211012

entonces la condicion Case que tengo es la siguiente

```
CASE 
WHEN FORMAT(cc.FechaCambioEstado,'yyyyMMdd')='' THEN FORMAT(ch2.Changed,'yyyyMMdd')
ELSE FORMAT(cc.FechaCambioEstado,'yyyyMMdd')  
END         AS [Fecha Cambio Estado]
```

Sin embargo no me funciona, alguien que me ayude si esta correcto la aplicacion del format dentro del `CASE` o faltara algo mas

Esos campos que estoy aplicandoles formato son tipo `DATETIME`

[image]

Comment: ¿En que situación la fecha tendría que ser una cadena vacía? Creo que estás confundiendo la validación de valores nulos.

Comment: En algunas situaciones la fecha no me genera NULL si no que se genera vacio el campo, e ahi por el cual coloco esa condicion, pero no funciona

Comment: ¿Cuál es esa situación? Ningún valor de datetime va a regresar una cadena vacía usando la función Format(). Además, sería mejor que usaras `CONVERT( char(8), cc.FechaCambioEstado,112)` para hacer la consulta más eficiente.